# How to add IronPython stubs to jedi?

Tags: python, ironpython, python-jedi

How to add a path for python jedi autocompletion. I downloaded Atom and the autocomplete-python package where I had the option to add the path to mine IronPython stubs. This works perfectly. I'm currently using jedi in a script and want it to look at the same IronPython stubs path that Atom does but can't find any information on how to do this

Some more information as my question was not clear enough.

I want to use the jedi library [as shown here](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) at the jedi documentation. I want jedi to look at my module with python files that are filled with mock objects for more completion suggestions as right now jedi only looks at the modules inside my python path

Comment: Please add a bit more information about how you are using Jedi. Are you using Jedi as a library? Or are you using it within a plugin for an editor?

Comment: As a library. I created the stub files with mock objtects with an IronPython library. So what I'm trying to do is just call script.completions() and get back the possible completions. Like here https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but I want to also look at my own module with the mock objets python files

Comment: Does the `sys_path` maybe help? You could just use `Script(..., sys_path=list(sys.path) + [my_iron_python_path])`.